# Change color of particular value on XAxis in MPAndroid Chart(Bar Chart)

Tags: android, graph, charts, mpandroidchart

I want to change the color of selected XAxis in MPAndroid graph(Bar chart)

Below is my code.

```
 XAxis xl = mChart.getXAxis();
 xl.setTypeface(tf);
 xl.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);

 s = new String[]{"S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "St"};

 ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            xVals.add(s[i]);
        }
```

Method for select the XAxis

```
 @Override
    public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {

        Log.i("X val", "Selected X Valu: " + s[h.getXIndex()]);
        if (e == null)
            return;

        RectF bounds = mChart.getBarBounds((BarEntry) e);
        PointF position = mChart.getPosition(e, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);   
    }
```

After select it,I want to change the color of `s[h.getXIndex()]`